# Cross Product Identity

Tags: proof-explanation, cross-product

I am trying to prove that
\begin{equation*}
(\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) \times (\vec{a} \times \vec{c}) = (\vec{a} \cdot (\vec{b} \times \vec{c}))\vec{a}.
\end{equation*}
I'd have a lot of false starts with this problem. I tried swapping the dot and cross product without any luck. I tried working from either the left-hand or the right-hand side, but neither seemed particularly easier.

I would really appreciate some direction on this. A hint while I continue to work on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product on the left side and expect one of the terms to be zero?

Answer (score 1):

Set $d=a\times c$. Then
$$(a\times b)\times d=(a\cdot d)b-(b\cdot d)a$$
by the vector triple product identity. But $a$ and $d$ are orthogonal
and also
$$b\cdot d=b\cdot(a\times c)$$
a scalar triple product etc.